# Do new QGIS installation packages uninstall or override any previously installed versions of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation

My organisation has restricted installing software on all workstations to I.T. administrators only, so I am not able to check this myself.

All applications, including QGIS, are pushed through Software Center.  Recently, they pushed QGIS 2.18.8 and it removed the last LTR version of QGIS and latest 2.18.6 version, from everyone's workstation.  I wanted to confirm, would the new QGIS 2.18.8 installer have uninstalled both the previously installed QGIS versions, or could it be something set in the Software Center distribution/installation process?

We would like to be able to always have a LTR version of QGIS to fall back on, if the test version has issues, so I am trying to narrow down the problem.

This is different to the suggested duplicate topic in that there is a software deployment application being used and not manual installations of QGIS to individual users. I want to determine if the uninstalls are done by Software Center or by the QGIS installation package by default. We also don't want standalone versions, preferring to run multiple QGIS versions. One LTR and one Latest for testing new features.

Comment: Ask your IT admin about what they put in the uninstall script. One can specify to uninstall several products before installing a new one

Comment: So you are saying it may be Software Center and not the QGIS installer, JGH?

Comment: On Windows7/10 they install in separate folders and will work side by side. If you have local admin you can install outside of the software manager.

Comment: While this is in the context of QGIS, its really "whatever your system admins decided and software deployment tools were set up to do", so I think its off topic for gis.SE. Consider that the answer would be equally applicable to notepad++ or a hex editor.

Comment: Ed: yes, your IT dept MAY have instructed to remove any product of the QGIS family before installing the new version. As @BradHards mentions, it is applicable to any software, script, file etc.

Comment: @BradHards: You are right, it can be applied to any application. However, when one doesn't have admin rights to their own workstation, and IT is saying the QGIS installer is removing the previous versions on installation, it then becomes more QGIS focussed. Granted it's not about its usage, rather its roll out. So before I go into a meeting, to argue their claim, I was hoping to get a better idea from others who are more experienced in installing QGIS and if it is in fact doing what they claim. They are blaming QGIS. I can't verify it.